# Pulling specific words from PDF using regex in R

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

[Click here to see the PDF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mktt8.png)

I am trying to pull `Start`,`Finish`,`Job Number` `Description` and `Tutor` from the PDF file above.

The following code is giving me `Start`,`Finish` and `Job Number`, but I also need to extract the rest of the texts for respective `Job numbers`.

```
a<-str_match_all(extracted_pdf, "(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})\\W+(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})\\W+(\\d+)")
```

Can you please help me on how to pull those texts and turn it into a table?

Comment: If possible, can you provide the PDF file? The link has a png file.

Comment: Not sure if you can upload PDF here, but I emailed it to you.

Comment: Thanks. I received it. Let me play with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my attempt for you. I provided explanation in my code. Dealing with PDF data is not easy; it requires some coding. But once you can find patterns, you can clean up data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(pdftools)
library(splitstackshape)

# Import the PDF, create a data frame, remove unnecessary columns and rows.
# I removed rows that were not included in the table.

foo <- pdf_data(pdf = "Client.pdf", opw = "", upw = "") %>% 
       as.data.frame %>% 
       select(-c(width, height, space)) %>% 
       slice(-(1:(grep(x = text, pattern = "^Start") - 1))) # Remove irrelevant rows.

# Get indices for dates. First, I identified which rows contain /, since / indicates dates.
# Then, I further subset the indices so that I can identify where each row of the
# table begins.

ind <- grep(x = foo$text, pattern = "/")
dummy <- c(diff(ind), NA)
ind <- ind[dummy == 1 & complete.cases(dummy)]

# Create a group variable with findInterval(). Concatenate texts for each group.
# Handle some string manipulation. Split the string and create columns.

group_by(foo, id = findInterval(x = 1:n(), vec = ind)) %>% 
summarize(text = paste0(text, collapse = "_")) %>% 
mutate(text = sub(x = text, pattern = "(Job|Tutor)_(Number|Name)", replacement = "\\1 \\2"),
       text = gsub(x = text, pattern = "(?<=,|Project)_", replacement = " ", perl = TRUE)) %>% 
cSplit(splitCols = "text", sep = "_", direction = "wide", type.convert = FALSE) -> res

# Set up column names
names(res) <- setNames(nm = c("id", unlist(res[1, ])[-1]))

# Remove the first row since it contains column names.
slice(res, -1) -> res

  id        Start     Finish Job Number                                  Description      Tutor
1  1   29/11/2019 29/11/2019    2288288 Project Name, Project Location, Project Type Tutor Name
2  2    2/12/2019  2/12/2019    8282888 Project Name, Project Location, Project type Tutor Name
3  3    9/12/2019  9/12/2019    2828288 Project Name, Project Location, Project Type Tutor Name
4  4 18/12//2019. 20/12/2019    2828289 Project Name, Project Location, Project Type Tutor Name
```

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly fine. Many thanks, @jazzurro. I have never worked on a text file before and now I will have to understand what you did here.

Comment: @user86907 No worries. If you are familiar with R to some extent, I think you see what I was doing in my code. If this case is done, click the green tick which is under the up/down vote arrows. If you case is closed, future readers know that the solution is working, which will help future reader. Please help to build a better community here. :)